How do I override the keyboard behaviors on a dndkit drag and drog
I've set up a simple drag and drop where theres 3 draggables and 3 droppables. I'm trying to change the default keyboard behaviour - however I've tried to intercept the KeyboardSensor and it seems that I can't change the behavior for the space and enter keys - they don't even register in the code:
import {
  MouseSensor as LibMouseSensor,
  KeyboardSensor as LibKeyboardSensor
} from '@dnd-kit/core';


function shouldHandleEvent(element) {
  let cur = element;
  return cur.dataset.noDnd === 'true';
}

export class MouseSensor extends LibMouseSensor {
  static activators = [
    {
      eventName: 'onMouseDown',
      handler: ({ nativeEvent: event }) => {
        return shouldHandleEvent(event.target);
      }
    }
  ];
}

export class KeyboardSensor extends LibKeyboardSensor {
  static activators = [
    {
      eventName: 'onKeyDown',
      handler: () => {
        return true;
      }
    }
  ];
}


Where you able to make it work?
